# parent and child(s) div size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one parent `div` and child `div`(s). Child `div`s vary from 2 to 10. At any given moment there are 2 child `div`s in parent `div`. But a third, fourth, fifth `div` could be added.

How to increase and decrease the height and width of the `div`s as the number of them increases and decreases?

Comment: `How to increase and decrease the height and width` --> and *how* you want the *how*?

Comment: This question is extremely vague, to the point of being just shy of nonsense. What have you tried? What, of what you have tried, is not working? Of what is not working what is the current outcome and what is the desired outcome? Since it appears you have tried nothing, I'm guessing you'll get that same number of answers.

Answer (score 0):

The parent div will grow with it's content by default. I've put together a simple demo demonstrating that. If the parent isn't growing, then you might have other css rules that are preventing that.

```js
function addchild() {
  var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  parent.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.parent div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addchild()">Add More</button>
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```